# MacBook Pro shuts down when unplugged

Tags: battery, power, shutdown

I have a late 2008 MacBook Pro work computer. Here's the sequence of events:

1. I fully charge the battery
2. I unplug the Mac from the power cable
3. The Mac immediately shuts down

Before unplugging the Mac, I press the battery power indicator button and all lights are green. When I unplug the Mac I press the indicator button again and only one light is green.

I've tried resetting the PRAM, SMC and even bought a new battery but the problem persists. [Here is the System Information](http://pastebin.com/Uukm3bU7).

How can I get my MacBook Pro to stay powered on when not plugged in?

**Update**: It was a dead battery. Apple gave me a new one for free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bought a new battery, and that didn't fix the issue then I would say it is a short in the logic board. If it is still under Apple Care, I'd take it into a store, or call 1(800)MY-APPLE to get it checked out, and serviced.

Comment: It is possible the new battery is bad. There are a lot of crappy counterfeit Apple MBP batteries out there. If it a genuine Apple battery, take it in to your local Apple Store.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your battery is dead. Your system report states that:

`37.   Condition:    Service Battery`

Time to either stay plugged to power, or get a new battery.

Comment: He already got a new battery, that's the strange part.

Answer (score -2):

This is really anormal. Have Apple repair your Mac.

Comment: @Bart - This ended up being the conclusion. And the solution.

Comment: I don't get it... The solution is lrussel810's answer. He states the same as you, but in a more elaborate way. In 2011.

Comment: @Bart - No. Ryan has updated his post now. The solution was to replace - again - the battery.

Comment: I've seen Ryan's update. But you do understand that your answer is very general and not helpful, right? Just stating the fact `this is really anormal` (yes, that's why the OP is asking for help) and following that up with very general advice to send it in for repair is not helpful considering the answers that were already present before you posted yours. Take a look at the [answer help section](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to see how to improve your answers.